# Typescript interface with React useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following 3 components:

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode, useContext } from 'react';

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode | ReactNode[];
};

interface State {
  functionalCookiesOn: boolean;
  performanceCookiesOn: boolean;
};

interface ContextProps {
  functionalCookiesOn: boolean;
  performanceCookiesOn: boolean;
  toggleAllCookies: () => void;
};

const CookiesContext = React.createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});

class CookiesProvider extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    functionalCookiesOn: true,
    performanceCookiesOn: true,
  };

  toggleAllCookies = () => {
    this.setState((prevState: State) => ({
      functionalCookiesOn: !prevState.functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn: !prevState.performanceCookiesOn,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    const {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
    } = this.state;

    const value = {
      functionalCookiesOn,
      performanceCookiesOn,
      toggleAllCookies: this.toggleAllCookies,
    };

    return (
      <CookiesContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </CookiesContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}


const Settings: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const {
    functionalCookiesOn,
    toggleAllCookies,
  } = useContext(CookiesContext);

  return (
    <Switch
      handleChange={toggleAllCookies}
      isOn={functionalCookiesOn}
    />
  );
};


interface SwitchProps {
  handleChange: () => void;
  isOn: boolean;
};

const Switch: React.FunctionComponent<SwitchProps> = ({
  handleChange,
  isOn,
}) => (
  <button onClick={handleChange} type="button">
    {isOn.toString()}
  </button>
);
```

The error I get is in the Settings component for both these lines:

```
handleChange={toggleAllCookies}
isOn={functionalCookiesOn}
```

The error for handleChange is:

```
Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
```

And

```
Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Can anyone explain this? As far as I can tell, I haven't told Typescript these values are optional anywhere and they're assigned values in the ContextProvider, so not sure why I'm getting the error.

I have tried initialising createContext with values rather than an empty object but that doesn't seem to help. Following [this link](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/context/#context-without-default-values) it looks like I haven't done anything different.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `Partial`. You are saying that all properties of `ContextProps` are optional which means they can be undefined.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Removing `Partial` throws an error on the empty object initialisation of createContext because it's missing values for the context props: `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ContextProps' ...`